# Slide show of strings in iphone App

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4

Is there any method for slide show of an array of strings in UILabel in iphone app?(ie, strings will appear one by one). Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

This can get you a repeated callback every X seconds.  You can use this to swap the strings in an array.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(swapStrings:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

_myStrings = @[ @"a" , @"b", ..... ];

... 

- (void) swapStirings:(id)sender 
{
    myInt ++;
    if (myInt >= [_myStrings count]) myInt = 0;
    myLabel.text = [_myStrings objectAtIndex:myInt];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.  But, the good news it should be trivial to implement.  I suggest creating a subclass of uilabel that has an array of strings as an ivar.  The subclass has an init method that sets the array and a time interval.  Then it uses an nstimer to change its label and redisplay itself.  Good luck!